# Gapless and non freeze playing of player items using AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, avqueueplayer

I have some issue with avqueueplayer like app freezing for 2-3 seconds when each item ends in the queue. I am using queueplayer to play the records one after the other without gap. In order to achieve no gaps b/w player items, I need to load the assets for a player item in advance. I load assets for current playing player item and next player item so that there will be no gap at the end of 1st record. As the 1st record ends, I add 2nd player item to queueplayer to play and also load assets for 3rd player item.

In this way my playerqueue always contains a single player item but asset loading will be done for current playing item and next playing item. This will keep moving as the new records are added.

I found that a freeze of half a second is observed in new iOS devices and around 3-4 seconds in old iPod devices like iPod 4?

Can I know how we can achieve gapless and yet non freeze UI experience?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try lifting your requirement to only have a single player item in the queue.

An `AVQueuePlayer` will operate more effectively at item transitions if there is an item in its queue beyond what's currently playing.

"Loading" media can mean a few different things, and it's not clear what you're doing. Maybe you're downloading media outside of AVFoundation, building an `AVAsset` or building an `AVPlayerItem`. The work you're doing or deferring will vary depending on the kind of media (*e.g* an mp4 vs an HLS stream). Even if you "preload" everything (which is much more complicated for HLS media), AVFoundation still has more work to do that it won't start until the `AVPlayerItem` is put in a player. It has to set up a render pipeline specific to the media it needs to play back, and then start the rendering process. `AVQueuePlayer` can achieve gapless playback by starting some of that process before playback for that item needs to start. The queue player is also efficient about its use of resources in that it won't start loading items far down the queue until it needs to.